# How to run all chuncks below when it is not working properly

Tags: r-markdown, execution

I am trying to execute my code in Rmarkdown using the "run all chuncks below" option with no results. It is not working and I have to execute chunck by chunck.

I would appreciate a lot if anybody can suggest me how to proceed to fix this

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There was an error in the final chunck which made not possible to work properly to the "run all chuncks below" option.

Comment: What was the error? Like your icon.